# Merge Multiple Files

Tags: windows

I have no programming experience but would like to do the following:

I would like to be able to select what files I want to merge from up to ten folders.  Once the selection was made...let's say a,b & d the program would then merge a,b & d from folders 1-10 and then merge the output from the ten folders into 1 file.....

Is this possible and what would be the best way to program this?

Folder # 1

File A - Merge
File B - Merge
File C
File D - Merge

Folder # 2

File A - Merge
File B - Merge
File C
File D - Merge

Folder # 3

File A - Merge
File B - Merge
File C
File D - Merge

Folder # 4

File A - Merge
File B - Merge
File C
File D - Merge

Folder # 10

File A
File B
File C
File D

Comment: What file format(s) would you be merging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want to do?:

```
@Echo OFF

:: By Elektro H@cker

Set "folder=C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Test"

Echo Selected Folder: "%FOLDER%"
Set /P "files=Select files to merge (Example: "File1.txt" "File2.txt" "File3.txt") >> "


For %%@ in (%files%) Do (
    For /R "%FOLDER%" %%# in (*) DO (
        IF /I "%%@" EQU "%%~nx#" (call Set "Files_to_merge=%%Files_to_merge%% "%%#"+")
        )
    )
)


Copy /A %Files_to_merge:~0,-1% ".\output_file.txt"
pause&Exit
```

PS: Remember to change the format of Copy command, /A for text files, /B for binary files.

**CMD Output:**

```
>Selected Folder: "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Test"
>Select files to merge (Example: "File1.txt" "File2.txt" "File3.txt") >>

>file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt

C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Test\file1.txt
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Test\Nueva carpeta\file1.txt
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Test\file2.txt
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Test\Nueva carpeta\file2.txt
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Test\file3.txt
C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Test\Nueva carpeta\file3.txt
        1 file(s) copied(s).

Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

**Output_file.txt contents:**

```
Content of "File1.txt" in first dir

Content of "File1.txt" in firstsub-dir

Content of "File2.txt" in first dir

Content of "File2.txt" in firstsub-dir

Content of "File3.txt" in first dir

Content of "File3.txt" in firstsub-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the append operator in Windows >> from the command line and just list out all the files you want to merge, like so.

```
Folder1\fileA.txt >> Folder10\merge.txt
Folder2\fileB.txt >> Folder10\merge.txt
Folder2\fileC.txt >> Folder10\merge.txt
Folder3\fileA.txt >> Folder10\merge.txt
```

If you want a batch program to ask the user for files and then merge it into a certain location you could do it like this...

```
:while1
    SET /P file=Please enter file name
    if NOT (%file%) == () (
        echo %file%
        %file% >> Folder10\merge.txt
        goto :while1
    )
```

Usually, if you have a file manipulation task scripting languages (like batch, perl or powershell) are more appropriate than programming languages. If you're going to do something very very simple in Windows, then batch can normally get the job done, otherwise I'd suggest using perl or powershell.

If you truly have no programming experience, then I would recommend going through some powershell tutorials http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/ , and spending some time learning that language. If that's too much of an initial investment for you, then I'd just recommend entering append commands into a .bat file like I did at the beginning and running it once. It will probably be faster than trying to write and debug your first script.

Comment: Can the bat have operator inputs for the merge?

Comment: Could the .bat ask...What files would you like to merge....and then the operator could select a,b, & d?